# How to calculate average temperature by day in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I have a schedule (air) that contains temperature information, including timestamps (time) and temperature values (temperature). I would like to summarize the average temperature of the data by day. How should I write the SQL

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL can be used:

```sql
select 
date_trunc('day', time) as day,
avg(temperature) as avg_temperature 
from air
group by day
order by day;
```